# C# connection with MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, reference, connection

once again im not really getting any further by just using google and searching through the forum, so here we go:

Im trying to establish a connection with C# and a MySQL Database (which is running on phpmyadmin).

This is the Code I got so far:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data;


namespace csharpdatabasefinal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C#: Connect to MySQL Database using localhost." + Environment.NewLine);
            string connectionString = "server=localhost;user=csharptest;database=csharptest;port=3306;password=123";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection is " + conn.State.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

                conn.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection is " + conn.State.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

            }catch(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit..");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Error I get, I guess it has something to do with the References but im not really sure..
I added as reference "MySql.Data.dll" & "System.Security.Permissions.dll".
I added the Systen.Security.Permission.dll because in a previous error he asked for it.

And this is the Error I get:

[Click me!(Error-Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TY0D.jpg)

Here the full Error Code:

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.
  Source=MySql.Data
  StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager.IsReplicationGroup(String groupName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at csharpdatabasefinal.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\anonym\source\repos\csharpdatabasefinal\csharpdatabasefinal\Program.cs:line 19

Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Dont worry about the different passwords, I changed both of them for the picture and the Code, even tho its only local ;)

Comment: Please include the full exception and stack trace as text in your question. Hint: click "Copy details" in that dialog in your screenshot.

Comment: I can't read all that error message in the screenshot but it looks like a file not found exception. Can you provide a full error message and maybe identify which file it says it can't find?

Comment: I just added the full error message, I also had the "System.Configuration" dll added but it didnt work as well if thats what you'd suggest.. :/

Comment: Have you tried enabling "native code debugging" in Project -> Properties -> Debug?

If not try adding the MySQL dll via nuget: Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 8.0.20

Comment: It worked after installing the package via Nuget, very weird but now it works! Thank you very much everyone! Especially @BrunoXavier! :) Have a good one!

Comment: I will add it as an answer then, so other people can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable "native code debugging" in Project -> Properties -> Debug

If that does't work, try adding the MySQL dll via nuget:

`Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 8.0.20`